# How to increase padding on custom view extending Button without scaling drawable?

Tags: android, button, numpad

I understand that it's easier to set padding without changing drawable size on ImageButton, however I am extending Button for my custom view as I need to override the OnTextChanged method (since Button extends TextView).

I have tried to set the padding programatically also, without success.

Part of my xml below:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?attr/backgroundColor">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center">

        <org.linphone.views.Digit
            android:id="@+id/Digit1"
            style="@style/DialerDigit"
            android:background="@drawable/ws_numpad_1"
            android:soundEffectsEnabled="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="1"/>

        <org.linphone.views.Digit
            android:id="@+id/Digit2"
            style="@style/DialerDigit"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_num2_group"
            android:soundEffectsEnabled="true"
            android:text="2"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <org.linphone.views.Digit
            android:id="@+id/Digit3"
            style="@style/DialerDigit"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_num3_group"
            android:soundEffectsEnabled="true"
            android:text="3"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    </TableRow>
```

Right now the buttons extend to match parent, but the drawables stretch as well. My aim is to achieve a dialpad similar to the native android one (i.e. where there is no gap in between digits and the numbers on the dialpad don't distort for different screen sizes).

**Edit 1 (dialpad image added):**

[image: This is the current view of my dialpad]

**Edit 2 (dialpad listener implementation):**

```
@Override
    protected void onTextChanged(CharSequence text, int start, int before, int after) {
        super.onTextChanged(text, start, before, after);

        if (text == null || text.length() < 1) {
            return;
        }

        DialKeyListener lListener = new DialKeyListener();
        setOnClickListener(lListener);
        setOnTouchListener(lListener);

        // Assign button long clicks here
        if ("0".equals(text.toString())) { // This was 0+, but they were separated, hence
            // changed to 0 only
            setOnLongClickListener(lListener);
        }

        if ("1".equals(text.toString())) {
            setOnLongClickListener(lListener);
        }
    }
```

```
private class DialKeyListener implements OnClickListener, OnTouchListener, OnLongClickListener {
        final char mKeyCode;
        boolean mIsDtmfStarted;

        DialKeyListener() {
            mKeyCode = Digit.this.getText().subSequence(0, 1).charAt(0);
        }

        private boolean linphoneServiceReady() {
            if (!LinphoneContext.isReady()) {
                Log.e("[Numpad] Service is not ready while pressing digit");
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
   ...
}
```

Comment: Can you show an image of what's happening now?

Comment: @ItayFeldman Hi Itay, image added.

Comment: It seems that because you are defining a background attr and not an image or src then its stretched on all the view as a background should behave.. Why wouldn't you want to change the extension to ImageButton? it seems the right thing

Comment: @ItayFeldman To be frank, I've downloaded the source code for the Linphone app and working my way from there. In it, there's a custom listener (also added in my answer above), which uses the `"text"` attribute of the button to retrieve the dialled number. I thought about going through the trouble of changing the implementation of the digits and listener, but wasn't sure if it was worth the time. If you also think changing to `ImageButton` is the best option, I will have to go for that.

Comment: Edited my answer to help you work with your implementation also after changing to ImageButton

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are working with a Button custom view and defining a background then the size of the button will be the size of the drawable you put as background.

Now you can just change your custom view to extend ImageButton and not Button and you'll be able to get it to work like this -

```
   <TableRow
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/Digit1"
            style="@style/DialerDigit"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_num1_group"
            android:tag="1" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/Digit2"
            style="@style/DialerDigit"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:soundEffectsEnabled="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_num2_group"
            android:tag="2" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/Digit3"
            style="@style/DialerDigit"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:soundEffectsEnabled="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_num3_group"
            android:tag="3" />

    </TableRow>
```

If you'd like to keep your implementation after changing to ImageButton the only difference will be -

Instead of initiating the listeners inside the onTextChange callback you can do it in an initListeners() method from the called once the view is created and adds its self the listeners it needs -

```
private void initListeners() {
    DialKeyListener lListener = new DialKeyListener();
    setOnClickListener(lListener);
    setOnTouchListener(lListener);
    setOnLongClickListener(lListener);

    // Assign button long clicks here
    if (Digit.this.getTag().toString().equals("0")) { 
        setOnLongClickListener(lListener);
    }

    if (Digit.this.getTag().toString().equals("1")) {
        setOnLongClickListener(lListener);
    }
}
```

And instead of getting the clicked button's number from the text of the button you put in the xml you can use tags exactly the same way.

I added tags to the xml example above and then once you have the view in the onClick callback you can just use getTag() to see what number it is

Comment: Thank you for your help Itay, I can't believe it worked (to be honest I was having a tough time understanding the methods). I put `initListeners()` inside the `init()` method, also using `Digit.this.getTag().toString().charAt(0) == 0` to get the long click functions of 0 and 1. I left the xml views as are, but instead changed them to extend `ImageButton` now, rather than `Button`. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ok you needed the long click for just those two then sure leave it that way, I'll edit the answer to do that too. Glad to see it's working :) just make sure you give the views the tags so you'll get back the correct number for all views later on.